# NullPointerException when autowiring @ConfigurationProperties POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I am trying to map a set of properties from a .properties file in a POJO object. This is because I want to reuse the properties in a @Configuration class and also because my property files are encrypted and I do not want to store the OAuth client passwords in plain text in the configuration class.

Here's the POJO:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreInvalidFields = false, prefix = "oauth")
public class OAuthClient {

    private Map<String, String> webapp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> admin = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getWebapp() {
        return webapp;
    }

    public void setWebapp(Map<String, String> webapp) {
        this.webapp = new LinkedHashMap<>(webapp);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Map<String, String> admin) {
        this.admin = new LinkedHashMap<>(admin);
    }
}
```

Everything looks good to me till now. I am exposing `OAuthClient` in a bean in the following config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuthClient.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:oauth_clients.properties")
public class OAuthClientsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OAuthClient oAuthClient() {
        return new OAuthClient();
    }
}
```

Here's the `oauth_clients.properties` file:

```
oauth.OAuthClient.webapp.id=client1
oauth.OAuthClient.webapp.secret=pass1
oauth.OAuthClient.admin.id=client2
oauth.OAuthClient.admin.secret=pass2
```

And finally, I want to use the properties in my custom `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, **but the app always fails to start with a NPE when getting the properties from the auwotired `OAuthClient`**.

Here's the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private OAuthClient oAuthClient;

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(oAuthClient.getWebapp().get("id"))
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(oAuthClient.getWebapp().get("secret")))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(PASSWORD_GRANT, REFRESH_TOKEN_GRANT, AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GRANT)
                .scopes(READ_SCOPE, WRITE_SCOPE)
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(6 * 60 * 60)
                .and()
                .withClient(oAuthClient.getAdmin().get("id"))
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(oAuthClient.getAdmin().get("secret")))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(PASSWORD_GRANT, REFRESH_TOKEN_GRANT, AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GRANT)
                .scopes(READ_SCOPE, WRITE_SCOPE)
                .autoApprove(true)
                .authorities(ADMIN_AUTHORITY)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 30)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60);
    }
```

Here's the complete stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project safedrive-auth-server: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project safedrive-auth-server: An exception occurred while running. null
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occurred while running. null
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup.rethrowUncaughtException(AbstractRunMojo.java:511)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithMavenJvm(RunMojo.java:93)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:243)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
        at com.adrianpop.AuthServer.main(AuthServer.java:11)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:80)
        at com.adrianpop.config.AuthorizationServerConfiguration.configure(AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java:76)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:708)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I've been struggling to get this to work for the few hours and it's hitting my nerves. I also checked the official documentation but the code looks fine to me. I know I am missing something simple, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add Stacktrace

Comment: Please check it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following snippet

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oauth")
public class OAuthClientConfig {

    private OAuthClient OAuthClient;

    public static class OAuthClient {

        private Map<String, String> webapp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        private Map<String, String> admin = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        public Map<String, String> getWebapp() {
            return webapp;
        }

        public void setWebapp(Map<String, String> webapp) {
            this.webapp = new LinkedHashMap<>(webapp);
        }

        public Map<String, String> getAdmin() {
            return admin;
        }

        public void setAdmin(Map<String, String> admin) {
            this.admin = new LinkedHashMap<>(admin);
        }
    }

    public OAuthClientConfig.OAuthClient getOAuthClient() {
        return OAuthClient;
    }

    public void setOAuthClient(OAuthClientConfig.OAuthClient OAuthClient) {
        this.OAuthClient = OAuthClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - the ```OAuthClient``` bean was successfully created before, but the maps were empty. Here's the result of the change you suggested: ```org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameException: Configuration property name 'oauth.OAuthClient' is not valid```

Comment: Have you tried @EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuthClient .class) on  AuthorizationServerConfiguration class ?

Comment: I've added the ```@EnableConfigurationProperties``` on the ```@Configuration``` class and also moved ```@ConfigurationProperties``` on the ```OAuthClient``` class, but I have the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that spring reads this @PropertySource("classpath:oauth_clients.properties")
?

Comment: I mean that it is not reading information from that file , thats why maps are empty

Comment: I've also tried placing the property set into ```application.properties```, still the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211563/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-adrian-pop).

Answer (score 1):

So, with the help of @Mykhailo Moskura the issue was fixed. The fix is a bit weird but well, this is how Spring works here.

I've created the `OAuthClientsConfiguration` class as Mykhailo suggested, and the POJO mapping the properties is an inner static class. Here's how the `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` looks like now:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuthClientsConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private OAuthClientsConfiguration.OAuthClient oAuthClient;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                            OAuthClientsConfiguration oAuthClientConfig) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.oAuthClient = oAuthClientConfig.getOAuthClient();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient(oAuthClient.getWebapp().get("id"))
                    .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(oAuthClient.getWebapp().get("secret")))
                    .authorizedGrantTypes(PASSWORD_GRANT, REFRESH_TOKEN_GRANT, AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GRANT)
                    .scopes(READ_SCOPE, WRITE_SCOPE)
                    .autoApprove(true)
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(6 * 60 * 60)
                .and()
                    .withClient(oAuthClient.getAdmin().get("id"))
                    .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(oAuthClient.getAdmin().get("secret")))
                    .authorizedGrantTypes(PASSWORD_GRANT, REFRESH_TOKEN_GRANT, AUTHORIZATION_CODE_GRANT)
                    .scopes(READ_SCOPE, WRITE_SCOPE)
                    .autoApprove(true)
                    .authorities(ADMIN_AUTHORITY) //check how to use this
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 30)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60);
    }
```

I've also managed to store the properties in a different file that the default `application.properties`, by adding a new property source:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources(value = {
        @PropertySource("classpath:oauth_clients.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
})
public class AuthServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServer.class, args);
    }
}
```